# Convert An ArrayList<db> To ArrayList<string>

Tags: android, listview

I need help understanding what I am doing wrong. I have a class ShoppingListDbHelper

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllShoppingList() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SHOPPINGLIST_TABLE_NAME, null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ITEM)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_QTY)) + " "
                + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_SIZE)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_BRAND)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ID)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

And I created an adapter like so

```
public class ShoppingListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShoppingListDBHelper> {
    public ShoppingListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShoppingListDBHelper> shoppinglists) {
        super(context, 0, shoppinglists);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        ShoppingListDBHelper shoppinglist = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView slItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewShoppingListItem);
        TextView slQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewShoppingListQty);

        slItem.setText(shoppinglist.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ITEM);
        slQty.setText(shoppinglist.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_QTY);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And when I try to do this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shopping_list_view);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ShoppingListDBHelper shoppingList = new ShoppingListDBHelper(context);

    ArrayList<ShoppingListDBHelper> shoppinglist;
    shoppinglist = shoppingList.getAllShoppingList();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingListView);

    ShoppingListAdapter adapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(context, shoppinglist);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I get an error in `ShoppingListAdapter adapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(context, shoppinglist)` that basically says Can't use `ArrayList<ShoppingListDbHelper>` in `Array<String>`.  I tried changing from ShoppingListDbHelper to String, but then I can't access the items like this  `slItem.setText(shoppinglist.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ITEM);` anymore.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u post full adapter code !!

Comment: Done.  I've tried changing it to extends ArrayList<String>, but that's when I can't access the elements.

Comment: Can u quote the exact error that you get ?

Comment: ShoppingListAdapter (Context, java.util.ArrayList<ShoppingListDbHelper>) in ShoppingListAdapter cannot be applied to (Context, java.util.ArrayList<String>).

Comment: I understand that I can't use my custom class in an String array, but what I don't understand is how to convert one to the other, of if that is even the solution.

Comment: Of course at the end of the day, I think I'm just using the wrong "stuff".  I think I need to rewrite it to use a cursor instead of the way I'm doing it.

Comment: Oh, yeah it is obvious, you are returning String type list and assigning it to a List of type ShoppingListHelper , it won't work !!

Comment: Why are you storing data in String type list. Simply use you ShoppingListDbHelper class

Comment: I've changed public ArrayList<String> getAllShoppingList() to public ArrayList<ShoppingListDBHelper> getAllShoppingList(), but i get this error  Add to ArrayList cannot be applied to java.lang.String.

Comment: Just changing the return type won't work. You must store data into a ShoppingListDBHelper type list. YOu will need to stop using Arraylist<String> type list since u have ShoppingListDBHelper type list in adapter

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understood @varunkr comments and below is the changes you need to make.

```
public ArrayList<ShoppingListDBHelper> getAllShoppingList() {
    ArrayList<ShoppingListDBHelper > array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SHOPPINGLIST_TABLE_NAME, null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        item=new ShoppingListDBHelper();//create one item

        item.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ITEM=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_ITEM));
        item.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_QTY=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_QTY));
        //do the same other objects of ShoppingListDBHelper
        //item.SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_BRAND=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(SHOPPINGLIST_COLUMN_BRAND));
        //add item to the arraylist
        array_list.add(item);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```